# C# - Sorting a ListBox by the ending

Tags: c#, regex, sorting, listbox, alphabetical

I have a ListBox that contains some data like below:

```
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0    0603_5
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0    0603
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90   0402_1
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0    0402
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  180  0402_3
Q7      IC-00268G   258.460  205.594  0    SOT236
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90   0402_3
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0    0402
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90   TANT3216
R21     CAP-00129G -123.370 -112.114  270  0402_3
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0    0402_9
...     ..........  .......  .......  ...  ........
```

I would like to sort the ListBox by the ending on the strings... so the values in the **6th** column (0603_5, 0603_5, 0402_2, 0402_4, 0402_3, TANT3216, 0402_9....).

---

*Although not all of these are shown in the file example above, here is the order of which they should appear (top to bottom):*

**`RES, 0402, 0201, 0603, 0805, 1206, 1306, 1608, 3216, 2551, 1913, 1313, 2513, 5125, 2525, 5619, 3813, 1508, 6431, 2512, 1505, 2208, 1005, 1010, 2010, 0505, 0705, 1020, 1812, 2225, 5764, 4532, 1210, 0816, 0363, SOT.`**

Also, if there are multiple endings that are similar (see *0402_3* above and below), then the list item will be sorted by the **2nd** column. So even though the line beginning with `R21` comes after the line beginning with `C25`, and they both end with *0402_3*, `R21` will be placed above `C25`  because it the 2nd column is checked after the 6th column (this is sorted from smallest to largest).

**SO,** the new file would look like this:

```
C18     CAP-00129G  230.960  190.619  0    0402
C56     EXCLUDES    229.430  189.374  0    0402
R47     EXCLUDES    226.935  179.519  90   0402_1
C17     CAP-00129G  250.085  198.569  180  0402_3
R21     CAP-00129G -123.370 -112.114  270  0402_3
C25     CAP-00130G  255.635  189.669  90   0402_3
R10     EXCLUDES    246.560  203.894  0    0402_9
C45     EXCLUDES    244.102  193.387  0    0603
C44     EXCLUDES    237.910  193.469  0    0603_5
R42     EXCLUDES    241.010  192.194  90   TANT3216
Q7      IC-00268G   258.460  205.594  0    SOT236
...     ..........  .......  .......  ...  ........
```

**Notice the `TANT3216` comes before `SOT236` because it is going off of the number *3216* not *TANT* in the above ordering list.**

---

***QUESTIONS:***

- How can I properly sort the first file to look like the second file using the **6th** column (and if needed the **2nd** column)?
- Could I use Regex or is there a simpler way?
- I have 3 ListBoxes, this 1 needs to be sorted using the rules (endings) above, the 2nd ListBox uses seperate rules, and the 3rd ListBox sorts anything else that did not go into the 1st or 2nd ListBox. So the 1st and the 2nd ListBoxes are similar, so how could I go about sorting anything by its endings *alphabetically* for the 3rd ListBox?

Comment: Your TANT3216 / SOT236 example is still unclear, 3216 comes after 216.

Comment: where is the data comming from?  it would probably be easier to sort before putting it in to the listbox,  you are probably going to end up writting a custom sort routine as the data is not in a traditional a-z type order.

Comment: @Henk: If you look at the order of the endings, there is no 216 so it is based off of the **SOT** which is the last item in the order list. However, with the 3216, there is a match in the list of order endings so it grabs that since there is not one for **TANT**.. is that more clear?

Comment: @Stuart: It is coming from a text file and being placed into a RichTextBox, and then moved to a ListBox for user functions. I was thinking I could sort it in the RichTextBox before it is placed into the ListBox, but I still do not know how I could go about that.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Create a class with properties for your columns. Maybe you already have that, it's not clear. Otherwise you'll have to break up the strings.

Step 2:

Create a LINQ query that uses `OrderBy(x=> x.Col6Property).ThenBy(x=>x.Col2Property)`

Step 3:

Add the List of objects to your Listbox and use an overridden ToString() or ListBox.Format to get the output you want.

Comment: I do not have a class with properties of my columns. I am also unfamiliar with *LINQ*... Any more suggestions or help you can give me? :)

Comment: You'll have to make such a class. Any attempt to do this text-based is doomed.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this by implementing the IComparer interface for the type that you are dealing with.  If the data is all tab separated strings, then you could use the following:

```
public class DropBoxStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    #region Implementation of IComparer<in string>
    Col2StringComparer col2 = new Col2StringComparer();
    Col6StringComparer col6 = new Col6StringComparer();
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        char[] tab = new[]{(char) 9};
        string[] xParts = x.Split(tab);
        string[] yParts = y.Split(tab);
        var c6compare = col6.Compare(xParts[5], yParts[5]);
        if (c6compare != 0)
        {
            return c6compare;
        }
        else
        {
            return col2.Compare(xParts[1], yParts[1]);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Col6StringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    #region Implementation of IComparer<in string>

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        //Rules that determine order of col 6

    }

    #endregion
}

public class Col2StringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    #region Implementation of IComparer<in string>

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        //Rules that determine order of col 2

    }

    #endregion
}
```